# Ошибка в коде: c6385 Чтение недопустимых данных

Tags: c++

господа. Собственно, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при заполнении двумерных массивов, в коде вылезает такое предупреждение и срабатывает стоп.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << "Введите количество строк и столбцов в массиве: ";
    int n, k;
    float s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s0 = 0;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    int** mask;
    mask = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mask[i] = new int[k];
    }
    cout << "\nВведите элементы массива: ";
    int** mass;
    mass = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = new int[k];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cin >> mass[n][k];
        }
    }
    cout << "\nВведите элементы маски: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cin >> mask[n][k];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            s1 += mass[n][k];
        }
    }
    s0 = n * k;
    s2 = s1 / s0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; i++)
        {
            if (mask[n][k] == 0)
            {
                mass[n][k] = mass[n][k];
            }
            if (mask[n][k] == 1)
            {
                mass[n][k] = mass[n][k] + s2;
            }
            if (mask[n][k] == 2)
            {
                mass[n][k] = mass[n][k] - s2;
            }
            if (mask[n][k] == 3)
            {
                mass[n][k] = s2;
            }
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Лично у меня скомпилировалось без предупреждений с флажками `-std=c++14`, `-Wall`. Однако, я заметил, что вы во многих местах написали `mass[n][k]`, `mask[n][k]`, где на самом деле, вы скорее всего имели в виду `mass[i][j]` и `mask[i][j]` соответственно.

Comment: Да, только сейчас в крайнем цикле появилось тоже самое даже после правок :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас при заполнении массива неправильно указаны индексы, 
        во всех циклах

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; i++)
        {
         ..........
        }
    }
```

нужно заменить `[n][k] на [i][j]`
   например:
   вместо    `mass[n][k]; - mass[i][j];`

вместо     `mask[n][k]; - mask[i][j];`
      и так далее